# Grouping anagrams efficiently

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, grouping, anagram

I am trying to write a program that will group all anagrams in a list together, and the output has to be sorted alphabetically. I already have a program to sort the input alphabetically which does it in O(nlog(n)) time using heapsort. My program also groups the anagrams, however it is too slow. I believe using hashing will give an efficient algorithm but not quite sure how to implement it. Does anyone have any suggestions for an efficient algorithm to complete this task?

eg.

Input:

```
eat tea tan ate nat bat
```

Output:

```
ate eat tea

bat

nat tan
```

Comment: What is your current (slow) grouping algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking at it wrong. From what I understands, you first sort strings by alphabetical order, and then try to seperate them to groups.

Try doing it the opposite. First, group the strings into anagrams, and only then, sort each group.

Grouping the anagram can be done in various ways, here is one of them:

1. Sort each string into an anagram. This means, each anagram is itself sorted. For example: eat,tea, nat will all be sorted to the string "aet". (Remember the original form of each word for later usage).
2. Once each word is "anagram sorted", you can simply use a hash table to group all of them, by using a `Map<String,List<String>>` - where key is the "sorted anagram", and the value is a list containing all original words.
3. Once you have this map, you need to sort each list which is a value in this map, and this is your final output.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, hashing it is.

You can use the following hashing technique: (Assuming your strings are all without space and have only lower case characters, and if they are having upper case, it will be treated differently (cat and Act are not anagrams then))

Hash value of a character will be the square of its ascii value, ie.

```
a = 97*97, b = 98*98, etc.
```

Add up the character values in every word, that will be its hash value.

Now, group together words with same (equal) hash value.

PS: if cat and Act are anagrams, convert `A` to `a` before computation.

PPS: In response to @amit's comments, I squared ASCII value of each character to reduce collisions, but, this won't be absolutely collision free. You can use *square of n^th Fibonacci number* as hash value, and then add them. This reduces collision even further.
So, hash values will be like:

```
a = 98^2, b = 99^2, c = (98+99)^2, d = (b+c)^2 and so on...
```

Comment: Going to assume all characters are feasible, this will fail for `"d"` (ascii=100) and `"\n\n"` (ascii=10 for each).

Comment: A word would not have spaces and is of only lower case characters. (Assumption)

Comment: `\n` counts as space.

Comment: In general, it works iif there is a unique prime number that is a factor of each hash code (that means, for each hash code `x`, there is a prime `p` that is a factor of `x` and is not a factor of each hash code `y!=x`).

Comment: Oh Correction. You add up the values, not multiple them. That sounds even more broken., for example - a string consisting of 98*98 chars, all a's , will have the same hash code of a string cosisting 97*97 characters, all b's.

Comment: Yea, adding is definetly not going to work, for the fact that a*b = b*a, so if you have two characters, one with value `x` and one with value `y`. repeating the one with `x` y times is going to be the same as the other way around. Playing with hashes is risky unless you know what you're doing. better leave it for experts and reduce the problem rather then reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, for that only I squared the numbers, and then I'm adding. This reduces the probability of collision exponentially. Another approach could also be used, to give hash value to each character square of nth Fibonacci number.